# LINQ to Entities - Addressing class properties with their string names

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid that has serverside filtering turned on. The field to filter by is passed as a string. For example, I want to filter by "SampleId". Now, I need to write a LINQ to Entities query that can filter by using the strongly-typed property SampleId. For example:

```
    db.Cases.Where(x=>targetlist.Contains(x.SampleId))
```

where targetlist is a list of items from the filter.

So, in effect, is there a way to write a query such that "SampleId" can directly translate to Case.SampleId?

I have tried reflection and made use of the GetProperty and GetValue and LINQ to Entities does not like it.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

---

EDIT (by pid for original poster srinaik2020):

@zaitsman: this is the code posted in an comment further below and is the actual resolution of the problem, based on the accepted answer.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string GetPropertyByName(this CaseV case1, string name)
    {
        var x = typeof (CaseV).GetProperty(name).GetValue(case1);

        if (x != null)
        {
            return x.ToString();
        } else {
            return "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The whole *point* of using something like EF is to *avoid* doing stuff like this.  The *idea* is to have compile time type safety.  If you don't want that, just don't use the whole feature and go back to a more traditional method of parameterized queries written out as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an extension method and attach it to the class.

That method should use reflection to retrieve the property from the object.

Here are the pointers:

- [Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)
- [GetProperty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Once this is working, you'll want just to set and/or get the value of the property.
The `GetProperty()` method above just returns the `PropertyInfo` object.
To get or set the value you'll have to use the appropriate methods of `PropertyInfo`.

I'd not expose the `PropertyInfo` because it would *ruin* the magic.

Better have to extension methods, then:

```
T GetPropertyByName<T>(string name);
SetPropertyByName<T>(string name, T value);
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding an extension method and calling it keeps LINQ to Entity happy.

Comment: @zaitsman Not sure what is the best place to put the code... so just pasting it here... Let me know if you were looking for something else. `          public static class MyExtensions
        {
            public static string GetPropertyByName(this CaseV case1, string name)
            {
                var x = typeof (CaseV).GetProperty(name).GetValue(case1);
                if (x != null)
                    return x.ToString();
                else return "none";
            }

        }`

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think any of these answered actually how to do the getproperty so included my working code after further research.  mymodelclass is the class of the entity/model used to MyFilteredData.

```
        var srchItem1 = typeof(mymodelclass).GetProperty("Name");
        var srchItem2 = typeof(mymodelclass).GetProperty("Description");
        var srchItem3 = typeof(mymodelclass).GetProperty("LongDescription");
        if (MySearchText != null && srchItem1 != null)
            {
                if (srchItem2 == null) { srchItem2 = srchItem1; }
                if (srchItem3 == null) { srchItem3 = srchItem1; }
                MyFilteredData = MyFilteredData.
                        Where(c => srchItem1.GetValue(c).ToString().ToLower().Contains(MySearchText.ToLower()) ||
                        srchItem2.GetValue(c).ToString().ToLower().Contains(MySearchText.ToLower()) ||
                        srchItem3.GetValue(c).ToString().ToLower().Contains(MySearchText.ToLower())
                );
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you like expressions, you can use them to get the value of a property like so (taken from some helpers i have made in LinqPad so it might not be full code):

```
public static class Helper {

    public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>( this IEnumerable enumerable, string memberName ) {
        IQueryable queryable = enumerable.AsQueryable();
        LambdaExpression expression = PredicateFor( queryable.ElementType, memberName );
        return CreateQuery( queryable, "Select", new[] { expression.ReturnType }, expression ).Cast<T>();
    }

    public static MemberExpression NestedPropertyOrField(this Expression expression, string nestedPropertyOrFieldName) {
        MemberExpression e;

        if (nestedPropertyOrFieldName.IndexOf('.') >= 0) {
            var split = nestedPropertyOrFieldName.Split(new[] { '.' }, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (split.Length > 0) {
                e = Expression.PropertyOrField(expression, split[0]);

                if (split.Length > 1) {
                    e = NestedPropertyOrField(e, split[1]);
                }
            } else {
                throw new ArgumentException("'" + nestedPropertyOrFieldName + "' is not a member of type '" + expression.Type.AssemblyQualifiedName + "'");
            }
        } else {
            e = Expression.PropertyOrField(expression, nestedPropertyOrFieldName);
        }

        return e;
    }

    private static IEnumerable CreateQuery( IEnumerable enumerable, string method, Type[] typeArguments, params Expression[] arguments ) {
        IQueryable queryable = enumerable.AsQueryable();
        Type[] typeArgs = new[] { queryable.ElementType }.Concat( typeArguments ?? new Type[ 0 ] ).ToArray();
        Expression[] args = new[] { queryable.Expression }.Concat( arguments ?? new Expression[ 0 ] ).ToArray();
        MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression = Expression.Call( typeof( Queryable ), method, typeArgs, args );
        return queryable.Provider.CreateQuery( methodCallExpression );
    }

    internal static LambdaExpression PredicateFor( Type elementType, string memberName ) {
        var pe = Expression.Parameter( elementType, "@item" );
        Expression expression = pe;

        if ( memberName.StartsWith( "@item", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ) {
            memberName = memberName.Substring( 5 );
        }

        if ( memberName.Length > 0 )
            expression = NestedPropertyOrField( expression, memberName );

        var delegateType = Expression.GetFuncType( elementType, expression.Type );
        return Expression.Lambda( delegateType, expression, new[] {pe} );
    }
}
```

and then do

```
string propertyName = // get property name from somewhere, ie: "SomeObject.NestedProperty.ID"
db.Cases.Select<string>(propertyName).Where(targetlist.Contains);
```

Comment: If you want to call the method on an `IQueryable` just call it on an `IQueryable`, don't have it be called on an `IEnumerable` and try to convert it.  It's more work on you, and implies to the caller that it will perform the work in LINQ to objects.

Comment: Its done like that so one method can handle IQueryable, ITable, DbSet, IEnumerable etc.

Comment: @DariusL. I guess  OP want just this(the part you omitted) `string propertyName = // get property name from somewhere` . Getting the property name from strongly-typed property

Comment: You can just write it for `IQueryable` and if someone wants to pass in an object that will use LINQ to objects they can just use `AsQueryable` themselves.  This method is also excessively verbose in how it handles expressions and particularly fragile.